# Save Firestore console filter settings

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I love the filtering capabilities in the Firestore console, but is there any way to save them? Every time I re-open to check something I end up having to re-filter/sort for a number of collections:

[image]

Does anyone know if it's possible to save these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to save the Firestore filter settings in the Firebase console. But it sounds reasonable, so I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).